# Correcting a possible roofing error

Tags: roof

Our roof has a peculiar first row of shingles. In most places the first row extended beyond the L-Shaped metal holder by about 5/8". But in some other places it is almost flush with the metal piece. (And in these places we noticed deterioration of fascia boards.)

If this is an error, what is a corrective step?

Answer (score 2):

On the roofs I've done, the shingles (or metal, in one case) extended 1/2" to 1" past the flashing.  It does not sound like this is the source of the problem for you.  The flashing should protect the fascia from a full water flow, if it is the correct flashing.  You describe it as L shaped, but it should have a kick out at the bottom ("drip edge").  [I found a decent picture here.](https://www.bestmaterials.com/detail.aspx?ID=22063&gclid=CjwKCAjwztL2BRATEiwAvnALcojkE_XgXFGqqUKPseENCugC6QZU_s5NeiRTrqEYn8eeWCR-rp6JfBoCtyAQAvD_BwE)

In addition to a small overhang and proper flashing, the final defense for your fascia is a coat of paint.  If the fascia is not rotten, you should restore its surface, and prime and paint.

Comment: "*If it it is the correct flashing*" AND it is installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

So much flashing used these days is the L-shaped stuff. I personally think this style is far superior because it supports the shingle overhang beyond the fascia board and still has the drip edge.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.roofingdirect.com/shop/style-d-drip-edge-with-1-3-4-face-and-3-1-2-roof-return-30-lineal-feet?attribute_pa_color=ac-brown&utm_source=Google%20Shopping&utm_campaign=Google%20Live&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=9667)*</sup>

Comment: Great picture, Michael